# Segmentation fault when accessing dynamically allocated array in a function

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to create a function that fills multiple arrays with data. The problem is, I get a segmentation fault whenever I try to put in more than 2 numbers. It works fine when I don't use a double pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readInput(int **array); 

int main()
{
    int *array;
    readInput(&array);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}

int readInput(int **array)
{
    int n,i;
    printf("Enter n:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    *array = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
scanf("%d",array[i]);
```

Since array is an `int**`, `array[i]` is an `int*` (ie index 0 is the pointer to the array you just allocated, the rest is random unallocated memory)

`(*array)[i]` is probably more like what you're looking for.

Comment: @IvoGörner Since `scanf` wants a pointer to the location where you want the int saved, you need to use `scanf("%d", &(*array[i]))` (or the somewhat slightly operator dense `scanf("%d", (*array)+i)`